# Is there an Android reading app that synchronizes across devices?

Tags: ebook-readers, synchronization, apps, sync

I have been using Aldiko and Kindle for reading on my Android devices, but I find it annoying to always have to convert epub books to mobi format just so I can synchronize them across devices using Whispersync.

There is an Aldiko Sync app, but it requires root privileges and I have not rooted any of my devices and I don't want to.

Is there an app that can synchronize, especially reading progress, across devices? Even an open source project where I have to run something on my own server would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

**Moon+ Reader** can do this, storing the data in Dropbox or in Google Drive.

(Note: I have not actually tried this functionality myself as I can't bear to use Moon+ due to its horrible UI and poor support for the ePub standard. But the feature is there in the settings, if you can find the right settings page...)

**Google Play Books** does so too - but it does not directly open files stored on the device (you have to let it upload them to Google's servers and then download them again...)

Comment: It works with either Google Drive or Dropbox, though getting Moon+ to actually link with Drive can sometimes be a real pain (I usually have to force it to create a settings backup there, otherwise it won't even acknowledge it exists as a location).

Comment: Oh, also. Google Play Books, but it only works for EPUB and PDF formats.

Comment: Which version of Google Books are you using? None that I tried were able to display a book

Comment: beware that with Google Play Books you won't be able to search unless you bought your books on google store

Comment: What's so horrible about the Moon+ Reader UI or ePub support? Would you please name some other readers where those flaws are absent or solvable?

Answer (score 0):

If you download Overdrive on your PC, tablet and smartphone, it will sync your progress, bookmarks, etc.  You will need a library login and password.  Works for Android and Apple.